# Why are my event listeners only working for the last element?

Tags: javascript

The problem is that when I drag/drop a picture, it always gets put on the last letter.
Here's an image of what I am talking about:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
function mattes_draw_letter(x, y, width, height, letter, position)
{
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.style.position = "absolute";
  canvas.style.top = 0 + "px";
  canvas.id = "canvas_opening_" + position;
  canvas.style.zIndex = 5;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.fillStyle = '#bfbfbf';
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x + letter[0] * width, y + letter[1] * height);
  for (i = 0; i < letter.length; i+=2)
  {
    if (typeof letter[i+3] !== 'undefined')
    {
      ctx.lineTo(x + letter[i+2] * width, y + letter[i+3] * height);
    }
  }

  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  $("#mattes").append(canvas);
  canvas.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {drop(event, this);}, false); 
  canvas.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {allowDrop(event);}, false); 
  canvas.addEventListener("click", function() {photos_add_selected_fid(this);}, false); 
}
```

Here is the code that has the for loop:

```
function mattes_create_openings(openings)
{
  var opening_array = new Array();
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var opening_width = 0;
  var opening_height = 0;

  $(openings).each(function(i, el) {

    x = $(el).find("x").text() * ppi;
    y = $(el).find("y").text() * ppi;
    opening_width = $(el).find("width").text() * ppi;
    opening_height = $(el).find("height").text() * ppi;
    var type = $(el).find("type").text();
    var text = $(el).find("text").text();
    var ellipse = (type == "ellipse") ? " border-radius: 50% " : "";
    if ("letter" == type)
    {
      var letter = mattes_get_letter_array(text);

      var letter_width = (opening_width - (text.length * 0.5 * ppi)) / text.length;
      var space = 0.5 * ppi;
      var letterX = x;
      var letterY = y;
      var letter_height = opening_height;

      mattes_draw_letter(letterX, letterY, letter_width, letter_height, letter, i);
      letterX += (space + letter_width);

    }
    else
    {
      $("#mattes").append("<div id='opening_" + i + "' style='background-color: #bfbfbf; position: absolute; left: " + x + "px; top: " + y + "px; height: " + opening_height + "px; width: " + opening_width + "px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 4;" + ellipse + "'  ondrop='drop(event, this)' ondragover='allowDrop(event)' onclick='photos_add_selected_fid(this);'>&nbsp;</div>");
    }

    //TODO multiple openings max/min -x,y,width, height
    opening_array["x"] = x;
    opening_array["y"] = y;
    opening_array["opening_width"] = opening_width;
    opening_array["opening_height"] = opening_height;
  });
  return opening_array;      
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the `mattes_draw_letter` for every letter?

Comment: Tip: `function(event) {allowDrop(event);}` same as `allowDrop`. Also when you have to pass `this` as an argument, think twice, there's probably a better way to do it, `this` depends on how you call the function.

Comment: @putvande - yes the function is called for every letter, it's in a for loop

Comment: Seems to be the problem with closures. Can you show us the for-loop snippet?

Comment: The problem probably lies within the for-loop.

Comment: I added code that shows the for loop

Comment: @AnupVasudeva - what?

Comment: @Allison, mistakenly pressed Enter. Was it a CSS issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the event handlers, but the size of the canvas. The last canvas created was on top of the others so it was the only event that was being activated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your code inside $.each in a function call, like this:

```
 $(openings).each(function(i, el) {
    bindEvents(i, el);
 };
 function bindEvents(indx, ele) {
    // Code what you have written inside $.each originally
 };
```

Comment: I tried that and it still had the same effect as my original code.